# Bundler and wrong binstubs?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I run `rails s` or `bundle exec rails s` and I get this warning:

```
Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem.
This is deprecated, in future versions you may need to `bundle binstub rails` to work around a system/bundle conflict.
```

What does this mean? From looking around the bundler site, my understanding of binstubs is that you can set executables to them, so instead of running `bundle exec blabla` you can just do `bin/blabla`. So this error is saying my `bundler` isn't set to the right binstub?

When I run the `bundle binstub rails` I get this output

```
rails has no executables, but you may want one from a gem it depends on.
  railties has: rails
  bundler has: bundle, bundler
```

I do not understand what my system is trying to tell me, and it's not breaking anything, but I have a hunch this could turn into a  bigger issue if I don't fix it

```
ruby 2.0.0p247
```

which ruby

```
/Users/evan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
```

which bundler

```
/Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/bundler
```

Rails 4.0.2

Edit:

So, if I run the commands in the nag message:

```
  bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
  rake rails:update:bin         # Use the new Rails 4 executables
```

I end up getting `uninitialized constant Bundler` errors with `bundle exec` commands and the only way I've found to fix that is to rerun `bundle install --binstubs` which brings back the nag message at the start of this post.

Comment: Same issue here. Bundler 1.6.2, Rails 4.0.3, rbenv 0.4.0

Comment: Just updated to rails 4.0.5 and it's still giving me the nag issue. Do you get the same bundler errors I noted at the end of the post if you run the suggested commands?

Comment: Easy fix: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27460085/115363

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What worked for me was

`rm -rf bin/*`

Then open a new terminal session and

`bundle exec rake app:update:bin`

Comment: I had to run `bundle exec rake rails:update:bin` after deleting bin/*

Comment: I am using Spring. Neither of those worked for me. But `bundle binstub rspec-core` did work. I am so confused. So many binstub options.

Comment: The binstubs created using these methods "get rid of the error" at the cost of losing the speed benefit of using spring binstubs. Not worth it.

Comment: @nilbus this might interest you (spring is dead to me): http://www.collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2015/02/04/spring-is-dead-to-me/

Comment: I've never had whatever issues he had. *shrug*

Comment: As the top comment, but I needed to use `bundle exec rake app:update:bin`

Answer (score 8):

**Solution in my case:** - *Other solutions didn't work for me.*

---

**In your Rails directory:**

```
mv /usr/bin/rails /usr/bin/rails.old
bundle config --delete bin
rm -rf bin

# for rails 4.x:
rake rails:update:bin

# for rails 3.x:
bundle install --binstubs

# if you're using rbenv
rbenv rehash
rm -rf ~/.rbenv/plugins/{rbenv-bundle-exec,rbenv-gemset,bundler}
```

**Also be sure that bin/rails is added to the path like:**

```
PATH=./bin:$PATH
```

Good luck.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Had to it was important to do the last command: `PATH=./bin:$PATH` I went ahead and also made this change to my bash_profile. Doesn't seem like the best solution but it gets rid of the annoying message.

Comment: @newUserNameHere i'm glad that it solved your problem.

Comment: The binstubs created using these methods "get rid of the error" at the cost of losing the speed benefit of using spring binstubs. Not worth it.

Comment: @nilbus what do you mean?

Comment: Spring preloads the app for startup speed. `spring binstub --all` creates the binstubs that make use of spring (which is the cause of the warning). However the binstubs created using the methods in this answer don't use spring and lose the startup speed.

Comment: @nilbus this might interest you (spring is dead to me): http://www.collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2015/02/04/spring-is-dead-to-me/

Comment: May want to note that adding the `./bin` dir to your path can be dangerous. Better to use the [`.git/safe/../../bin` method](https://github.com/thoughtbot/suspenders/pull/282)

Comment: @TheLonelyGhost saying that that is dangerous is kind of saying that adding rm to your path is dangerous. i think it's a permission issue and a tradeoff.

Comment: @deeperx it is a tradeoff where cloning a git repo to experiment with it might risk your system. If, for example, there's a file bin/cd that runs rm -rf $HOME, it would be a problem. In an ideal world people won't clone untrusted repos, but this adds an extra measure of protection where one needs to explicitly whitelist it to add to their PATH.

Comment: @TheLonelyGhost as I said it's a permission issue as you have described. But, it's a valid one of course.

Comment: I prefer this approach for loading ./bin into PATH on a per-directory basis http://direnv.net/ /cc @TheLonelyGhost

Comment: I found that the change for bin/rails and bin/rake is same as below patch,

@@ -1,7 +1,8 @@
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby
 begin
-  load File.expand_path("../spring", __FILE__)
-rescue LoadError
+  load File.expand_path('../spring', __FILE__)
+rescue LoadError => e
+  raise unless e.message.include?('spring')
 end

Answer (score 1):

This error may raise when you update your ruby but not the related gems.

To check if this is your case, try to make a new rails app in a new empty directory (to be sure RVM is not autoloading any gemset)

```
make /tmp/test && cd test && rails new test
```

If this fails stating that it cannot find a suitable 'rails', then simply run

```
gem update
```

and overwrite any conflicting rails.

Answer (score 1):

```
gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler
```

Uninstalling all my versions of Bundler, and then installing the latest version fixed it for me. I had multiple versions of bundler installed, so when I ran `bundle exec rails s` I think the wrong Bundler was used, giving me the warning message.

You may need to generate new stubs after reinstalling Bundler, but I didn't have to.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix this by looking at the commit history for `bin/rails` using `git log -p bin/rails`

The current, error producing content is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
# This file was generated by Bundler.
#
# The application 'rails' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'pathname'
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path("../../Gemfile",
  Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)

require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

load Gem.bin_path('railties', 'rails')
```

The original, non-error content was:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

When I restored the original bin/rails content, the warning message disappeared. Previous attempts had returned `uninitialized constant Bundler` errors on all `bundle exec` commands, but now they work. It's worth noting that the original content appears to be exactly what `rails new blabla` generates in rails 4.0.x.

Still, I would like to know why the first code block causes issues because it's exactly what `bundle install --binstubs` generates.

Edit: turns out this solution does not work. Pushed this fix to a heroku staging server and heroku errors on startup: all `bin/rails` commands throw `uninitialized constant Bundler` and heroku starts up with `bin/rails server .....` so this is a not really a fix.

Edit2:

If I add these two lines to the second block (the original bin/rails content), all `bin/rails` commands are working again:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
```

My guess is that the second line is what fixes the bundler errors I was having.

Interestingly, when I tried to edit the first block of code in this post to try and debug which line was throwing the warning, any change I made caused all `rails` commands to failure, with no information except for the nag note in the OP. weird.

Final `bin/rails` that fixed my issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'rails/commands'
```

Any additional insight from people who find this would be welcome!