# How can I fix a bundler system/bundle conflict?

Tags: ruby, rspec

When I run `bundle exec rspec` for a gem that I'm developing, I receive this message.

```
Laptop:new_gem me$ bundle exec rspec
Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem.
This is deprecated, in future versions you may need to `bundle binstub other_gem` to work around a system/bundle conflict.
```

I have uninstalled `other_gem` from my machine and looked through the other stackoverflow questions but haven't been able to figure it out.

I'm using rbenv to manage my Rubies.

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165913/bundler-and-wrong-binstubs