# ActiveRecord Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-migration

Ive set up a database through active migrations before. However when i go to setup a new one on another project it doesn't seem right.
I am typing this into the command line

```
bin/rails generate migration Database Date:date Endpoint:text User:string Domain:string
```

However the output is this(snippet for brevity) :

```
Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem.
This is deprecated, in future versions you may need to `bundle binstub rails` to work around a system/bundle conflict.
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /Users/alexbozanic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control .keep files
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                # Don't install Spring application preloader
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                         # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                          # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                                         # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]        # Skip turbolinks gem
  -T, [--skip-test-unit], [--no-skip-test-unit]          # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--rc=RC]                                          # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                            # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file
```

What is going on? Thanks

Comment: Does this solution work http://stackoverflow.com/a/23658355/5076451 ?

Comment: I would bet that `Database`  is a reserve word, so you couldn't use it as a model/migration name. Change it to something else and it should be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might need to regenerate your binstubs. Try running:

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! After running rake rails:update:bin It successfully created the file e.g 0002020338_database.rb

Comment: This is the output:                                                                                  bin/rails generate migration Database Date:date Endpoint:text User:string Domain:string 
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20150716204130_database.rb
Why Didn't it create all of the columns in side the rb migrate file?

Comment: Perhaps the capital letters are throwing it off. Try with all lowercase

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using bin/rails generate (model) instead of migrate and it seemed to work just fine! Is this a proper solution? OR is there a significant difference between the two? Thanks!