# Heroku doesn't recognize 'spring' gem, even though it's listed in the Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring, heroku

I've deployed to Heroku in the past with very few issues. Today I created a very basic app (literally just the default 'new' with an updated gemfile) and pushed it up to Heroku.

However, Heroku doesn't recognize the 'spring' gem, even though it's listed in the Gemfile. It's causing my app to crash. And before it's asked, yes I have run `bundle install` and `bundle update` after updating the Gemfile.

Gemfile (Literally copy-pasted from RoR Tutorial):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '4.2.2'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',     '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Error message after running `heroku run rails console`:

```
Running rails console on pure-falls-2221... up, run.6936
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'spring' (= 1.1.3) among 59 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /app/bin/spring:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/bin/rails:4:in `load'
    from /app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Heroku Logs:

```
2015-11-17T02:00:32.426615+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-17T02:00:32.426624+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-11-17T02:00:35.179885+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 29889 -e production`
2015-11-17T02:00:37.945522+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
2015-11-17T02:00:37.945526+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-11-17T02:00:37.945524+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/bin/spring:12:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-17T02:00:37.945525+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `load'
2015-11-17T02:00:37.945523+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
2015-11-17T02:00:37.945512+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'spring' (= 1.1.3) among 59 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
2015-11-17T02:00:38.782080+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-17T02:00:40.980407+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 7751 -e production`
2015-11-17T02:00:38.801178+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-17T02:00:38.801178+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-17T02:00:43.123615+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'spring' (= 1.1.3) among 59 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
2015-11-17T02:00:43.123626+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
2015-11-17T02:00:43.123629+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
2015-11-17T02:00:43.123630+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/bin/spring:12:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-17T02:00:43.123630+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `load'
2015-11-17T02:00:43.123631+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-11-17T02:00:44.203452+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-17T02:01:05.291898+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pure-falls-2221.herokuapp.com request_id=adc1ccb9-cd90-45fd-b179-ef680f936c2f fwd="125.140.58.57" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-17T02:01:06.107852+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pure-falls-2221.herokuapp.com request_id=a92abeed-9b09-4ff8-b535-bac178eb454b fwd="125.140.58.57" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-17T02:01:19.376119+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by chrabyrd@gmail.com
2015-11-17T02:01:21.779621+00:00 heroku[run.6936]: Awaiting client
2015-11-17T02:01:21.797009+00:00 heroku[run.6936]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2015-11-17T02:01:22.153107+00:00 heroku[run.6936]: State changed from starting to up
2015-11-17T02:01:24.185437+00:00 heroku[run.6936]: State changed from up to complete
2015-11-17T02:01:24.169704+00:00 heroku[run.6936]: Process exited with status 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: would be helpful if you posted logs from heroku.

Comment: siaw23 - I wasn't sure if I should, there's not much documentation on code H10. However, they're there now.

Comment: Did you commit changes made to Gemfile and Gemfile.lock before deploying to Heroku?

Comment: mmicheal, yes I did.

Comment: Try specifying a Ruby version in your Gemfile. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions

Comment: pdoherty926: Did that, still didn't make a difference.

Comment: please update your Gemfile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the gem in the `development` group.  If you take it out of that group and put it in the main group, do another `bundle install`, add that to the repo and redeploy, I presume it will all work just fine.

Comment: This works, but raises even further questions. Every past app I've made starts with copy/pasting the Gemfile from the RoR Tutorial. And every time until now it has worked.

However, this solved my issue. Thank you!

Comment: This is ill advised. You don't want to be running Spring in production.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Rails and going through the tutorial as well.  I had this same issue.  Here is the answer after much looking and discussion with an experienced Rails dev.

Look in the bin/rails file at line 4 according to your log file: (here is that code.  Line 4 is where the error is happening.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
  spring_bin_path = File.expand_path('../spring', __FILE__)
  load spring_bin_path
rescue LoadError => e
  raise unless e.message.end_with? spring_bin_path, 'spring/binstub'
end
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application', __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

If you remove line 6, then the error will not be raised and spring will not be loaded.  This is what the previous versions of the bin/rails code did and all worked fine.  I don't know if it's Rails or Cloud9 or what is generating this code but something changed in the last couple days, no doubt.

NOTE: Be sure to leave the spring gem in the development group of gemfile.  I would not move the spring gem to the main group in the gemfile since Spring is not supposed to run on production no matter what from my limited knowledge.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Commenting this line worked for me.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I put in a ticket with the `spring` guys

https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/450

I am suspecting this has to do with the `spring` gem release version 1.4.4

Comment: Even with older gems, though?

Answer (score 1):

Until the Spring team come up with a better solution I have patched `bin/rails` and set a Heroku environment variable to avoid loading Spring in production:

`heroku config:set DISABLE_SPRING=1`

**bin/rails:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
unless ENV["DISABLE_SPRING"]
  begin
    spring_bin_path = File.expand_path('../spring', __FILE__)
    load spring_bin_path
  rescue LoadError => e
    raise unless e.message.end_with? spring_bin_path, 'spring/binstub'
  end
end
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

`DISABLE_SPRING` is [the recommended environment variable](https://github.com/rails/spring#temporarily-disabling-spring) as per their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of spring is 1.4.2. You may want to do spring as that version instead of the older version.

Comment: I'm on 1.4.4 and still seeing this problem - see my answer for a note about a temporary patch.