# System/bundle conflict in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring

I have a small issue ... while I run 'rails server' the following warning message occurs...

​
**Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem.
This is deprecated, in future versions you may need to `bundle binstub rails` to work around a system/bundle conflict.**

I have tried **bundle binstub rails** too.. that didn't solve the issue and i get this

**rails has no executables, but you may want one from a gem it depends on.
 railties has: rails
 bundler has: bundle, bundler**

I have looked in stackoverflow for the solution [Bundler and wrong binstub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165913/bundler-and-wrong-binstubs) .I tried that too, but did not solve the issue..